# Telling what type of data is what, Python

Tags: python, int

I would like to be able to tell if a variable is an int or not using an if statement in Python. How would I go about this.

Comment: There are no variables in Python, there are only objects and references to objects

Comment: @eyquem: There is no need to be formal here.  Of course there are variables in Python, the term is used many times throughout the official documentation, e.g. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers ("The equal sign ('=') is used to assign a value to a variable").

Comment: The next question is: Why do you need to do that? Usually you shouldn't need to do any type checking in Python. [Use "duck typing" instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python/1549854#1549854).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thanks for pointing. I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(var, int):
  print "Int"
elif isinstance(var, str):
  print "Str"
else:
  print "Other:", type(var)
```

Comment: There is also the 'types' module that you could use to help!

Answer (score 3):

```
if isinstance(x,int):
 print 'win'
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use isinstance:

```
value = 123
if isinstance(value, int):
    print "Int"
else:
    print "Not Int"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to detect if a variable in bound to an `int` or a value of *any derived type*, so `isinstance` is the solution...

... but it does not distinguish between say `int` and `bool`.
In Python 3:

```
>>> isinstance(123, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance(123, bool)
False
>>> isinstance(True, bool)
True
```

If you really need to know if a value is an `int` and nothing else, `type()` should be the way to go:

```
>>> type(123)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(123) == int
True
```